# JS Number Method not Working

Tags: javascript

I am newbie in JS and i cant understand this thing.. When i input any number in the first field, nothing appears in the next field but the code has to be working properly.. What is the error in this code?

```
   <html>
   <head>
    <title> Number methods </title>
     </head>
     <body>
   <table border="2px"  width="500px" height="400px" align="center">
  <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
           <p> Enter a number  </p>
      </td>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
         <input type="text" id="number">
      </td>
            </tr>   
           <tr> 
           <td align="center" colspan="2"> Result </td>
           <td align="center" colspan="2">  <input type="text" id="result">                     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>      
           <td align="center"> <input type="button" onClick="string();" value="String"> </td>
           <td align="center"> <input type="button" onClick="precision();" value="Precision"> </td>
           <td align="center"> <input type="button" onClick="expo();" value="Exponential">  </td>
           <td align="center"> <input type="button" onClick="fixed();" value="Fixed"> </td>

   </tr>        
  </tr>
</table>

   <script>
  function fixed()
     {

         var num = document.getElementById("number").value;

      var res = document.getElementById("result");
           res.value = num.toFixed(2);

     }
```

Comment: could yuo just make a JSFiddle , so that it will be easy

Comment: Ohh sorry will do next time :)

Comment: @SiddharthPrabhu Why don't you accept any answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string do not have a function called `.toFixed` in its prototype,

```
res.value = parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
```

You have to convert it as a number, so that you could access its function `.toFixed()`. Since you are caring for the decimal points I have suggested you using `parseFloat` for converting that string as a number.

Like wise you can also use `parseInt(str)`,`Number(str)`, `+str` to convert a string `str` to number.

Comment: @SiddharthPrabhu Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `num` variable is a string.  `.toFixed()` is only a method on a number object, not on a string.

You must convert `num` to a number before you can call `.toFixed()` on it.  Here's a corrected version of  your code that uses the `+` operator to convert to a number:

```
function fixed() {
    // use the + here to convert to a number
    var num = +document.getElementById("number").value;
    var res = document.getElementById("result");
    res.value = num.toFixed(2);
}
```

If you learn to look in the debug console in the browser, it should have told you exactly what line of code your error was on and given you a pretty good idea what was causing the error.